# Hcat and vcat return wrong types

Tags: types, julia

Hello people on the internet!

I am an almost total newcomer to programming and I use Julia for small quantum physical simulations. Basically I construct matrices and use Julia to diagonalize them. Until yesterday I used "JuliaPro" and it worked fine, but some things annoyed me and so I deinstalled it, downloaded the Atom Editor and the most recent Julia command line version (v0.6.1).

In case it might be relevant:
Upon trying to use "using PyPlot" I had to add the package first and encountered the Error described here: https://discourse.julialang.org/t/error-installing-pyplot-the-python-package-mpl-toolkits-mplot3d-could-not-be-found-by-pyimport/6372

I did some reinstalling of packages and switched to Anaconda as described here: https://github.com/JuliaPy/PyPlot.jl/issues/313

Now to the actual problem. I have a function where I build a larger matrix from smaller 2d arrays using hcat() and vcat(). The function looks like this:

```
function InfiniteHamil(E, EA, EAB, FA_list, FB_list, d_list, ϵ_list)
    #------------------------------ 
    num_steps = 200
    x_values  = collect(0:1/num_steps:1)
    y_values  = []

    #------------------------------
    for x in x_values
        k   = path(x)
        z1  = exp(im*k[1])
        z2  = exp(im*k[1]/2)*exp(im*sqrt(3)*k[2]/2)
        c1  = cos(k[1])
        c2  = cos(k[1]/2 + k[2]*sqrt(3)/2)
        c12 = cos(k[1]/2 - k[2]*sqrt(3)/2)

        secondHam = vcat( hcat(E+ 2*(c1*d_list[1] + c2*d_list[2]+ c12*d_list[5]),
                            FA_list[1]+ conj(z2)*(FA_list[2]+z1*FA_list[3]),
                            FB_list[1]+ conj(z2)*(FB_list[2]+z1*FB_list[3])),
                      hcat((FA_list[1]+ conj(z2)*(FA_list[2]+z1*FA_list[3]))',
                            EA+ 2*( c1*ϵ_list[1]+c2*ϵ_list[2]+c12*ϵ_list[5]),
                            EAB ),
                      hcat((FB_list[1]+ conj(z2)*(FB_list[2]+z1*FB_list[3]))',
                            EAB',
                            EA+ 2*( c1*ϵ_list[1]+c2*ϵ_list[2]+c12*ϵ_list[5]) ))

        #print types of constituents
        println(typeof(E+ 2*(c1*d_list[1] + c2*d_list[2]+ c12*d_list[5])))
        println(typeof(FA_list[1]+ conj(z2)*(FA_list[2]+z1*FA_list[3])))
        println(typeof(FB_list[1]+ conj(z2)*(FB_list[2]+z1*FB_list[3])))
        println(typeof((FA_list[1]+ conj(z2)*(FA_list[2]+z1*FA_list[3]))'))
        println(typeof(EA+ 2*( c1*ϵ_list[1]+c2*ϵ_list[2]+c12*ϵ_list[5])))
        println(typeof(EAB ))
        println(typeof((FB_list[1]+ conj(z2)*(FB_list[2]+z1*FB_list[3]))'))
        println(typeof(EAB' ))
        println(typeof(EA+ 2*( c1*ϵ_list[1]+c2*ϵ_list[2]+c12*ϵ_list[5])))
        println(typeof(secondHam))

        push!(y_values ,  filter(x -> x > -10, sort(real(eigvals(secondHam))) ))

    end
    #------------------------------ 
    y_values = hcat(y_values...)
    plotData(x_values,y_values)
end
```

As output, I get:
[console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sqWiI.png)

Basically, I only concatenate Arrays, but somehow my result becomes a Sparse Matrix... This hasn't happened (with the exact same code) before reinstalling. Can someone tell me what's going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So.. I resolved it on my own, but I don't really know the exact problem. However, it's got to do with the "Diagonal" type displayed in my output. Using diagm() instead of Diagonal() the error doesn't come up.

Comment: `Diagonal([1,2,3])` has a different output type to `diagm([1,2,3])`. Also note that the former is a constructor, while the latter is a function. Types, and more generally, multiple dispatch are core to the Julia language. A comment is not really the place to go into this in any depth, so I'm going to be lame and suggest you have a careful read of the official docs. This will take quite a big chunk of time, but, having come from several other, less satisfying, programming languages myself, I promise it is worth it.

Comment: I tried reading a bit in the official docs, but I find they're hardly educational, as they often miss explanations of the terms I don't know. Any supplementary info you can recommend for Julia?

Comment: I found the official docs to be amazingly good, but then again, I was coming from a background including Matlab, Python, R, and .NET. If you're a newcomer to programming the best thing you can do is keep working in Julia, and any time you're not sure of something, check the docs, check stack overflow, and if you still can't find a good resource, ask about it here or at the [julia discourse page](https://discourse.julialang.org/). Note it has a "first steps" tag. Do this for a year, and you'll be answering questions here by the end :-p